# ruby how to pass a method and invoke it with parameter

Tags: ruby

I tried to do the following in ruby, but it didn't work:

```
method_map = {
  'one' => one
}
def one(param)
  puts param
end

method_map['one']('hi')
```

then I realized that in ruby this will invoke the method before I even put parentheses, so I found out that I can pass a method name instead

```
method_map = {
  'one' => :one
}
method_map['one']('hi')
```

but it still doesn't work. What's the correct way of passing a method, and then invoking it with a parameter in ruby?

Comment: Your question would be improved by limiting it to asking why #2 doesn't work. It doesn't really matter at how you arrived at that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I shall edit it when I get back from getting foods : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it as follows using `send`

```
2.2.2 > send(method_map['one'], 'hi')
=> hi
```

Using `call`

```
2.2.2 > method(method_map['one']).call('hi')
=> hi
```

You can also use `eval` (not recommended)

```
2.2.2 > eval "#{method_map['one']}('hi')"
=> hi
```

Benchmark (1 million iterations)

```
       user     system      total        real
send  0.670000   0.000000   0.670000 (  0.668050)
call  0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.225053)
eval  4.920000   0.000000   4.920000 (  4.919729)
```

Comment: are these considered inefficient (from a performance point of view) in ruby? is it better for me to use if/else or a switch to check the string 'one' and invoke the method that way?

Comment: I've added a benchmark (ruby 2.2.2), ``call`` or ``send`` are both fine to use in terms of performance (``call`` has a slight edge).